# Image poster video tag stretch in IE9

Tags: html, video, poster

I have the follow code, use Flowplayer, and config as below:

```
<div class="flowplayer" style="width:800px; height:450px;">
<video preload="none" poster="cover.png">
<source type="video/mp4" src="video.mp4" />
</video>
</div>
```

the cover.png has size 800x450, it fit with the width and height of div container video tag.
And it look good on Firefox, and Chrome, but when I saw it in IE9, the cover image is fetched,   so is display not correct on IE9, maybe it zoom in, larger, so display only the center of image , other around is cut off.

How could I fix this issue? Because I think, size of poster is fit ok with container, not need stretch to make it fit anymore, why IE9 display as this.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add background image to the div as well